# Customizable timeout on MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Is there any way to do a customizable timeout for MyBatis configuration?

I am using MyBatis with Spring framework, but I cannot make the 'defaultStatementTimeout' property customizable, as PropertyPlaceHolder on Spring.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way, but only through of the MyBatis configuration file. You can add the location of MyBatis configuration file in your Spring configuration file (there is a [example](http://mybatis.github.io/spring/sample.html) in the MyBatis page) for load the [settings](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#settings) that you want:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="location" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" />
</bean>
```

The MyBatis configuration file can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="10"/> <!-- seconds -->
    </settings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, this isn't customizable.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem. I had to override the `SqlSessionFactoryBean` with a `CustomSqlSessionFactoryBean.`

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="com.myapp.CustomSqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:sql-config.xml" />
    <property name="timeout" value="${custom.timeout}" />
</bean>
```

My MyBatis config file looks like

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="${custom.timeout}"/>
    </settings>
</configuration>
```

My Custom implementation of `SqlSessionFactoryBean` overwrite the `buildSqlSessionFactory()` method, which set the timeout (replace ${custom.timeout} by timeout value in MyBatis config file).

```
@Override
protected SqlSessionFactory buildSqlSessionFactory() throws IOException {
    String strConfig = IOUtils.toString(CustomSqlSessionFactoryBean.class.getResourceAsStream(MYBATIS_CONFIG_PATH));
    strConfig = StringUtils.replace(strConfig, TO_REPLACE, String.valueOf(timeout));
    InputStream inputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(strConfig);
    setConfigLocation(new CustomClasspathResource(inputStream, strConfig));
    return super.buildSqlSessionFactory();
}
```

This class let me set the modified inputstream to the `setConfigLocation` method.

```
class CustomClasspathResource extends ClassPathResource {

    private InputStream inputStream;

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return inputStream;
    }

    private CustomClasspathResource(InputStream inputStream, String path) {
        super(path);
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }
```

Thus the timeout is customizable with the `${custom.timeout}` variable.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Batch it's possible set custom timeout on SystemCommandTasklet using the property "timeout" on bean

```
<bean id="FlxxtUpdaterTasklet" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.SystemCommandTasklet">
    <property name="command" value="xxx" />
    <property name="timeout" value="3600000" />
    <property name="interruptOnCancel" value="true" />
    <property name="terminationCheckInterval" value="5000" />
</bean>
```

With Mybatis for override the Statement Timeout using the property "timeout" on the mapper statement:

```
    <mapper namespace="com.xxxx.blsf.batch.mapperbls.Bls2CsvMapper">
        <select id="bls2csv" parameterType="com.xxxx.blsf.batch.mapperparams.SpParamInteger" 
            statementType="CALLABLE" timeout="6000" >
            { CALL PKG_BLACKLIST_PLUS_RC.BLS_2_CSV(#{rcInt, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER, javaType=java.lang.Integer})}
        </select>
    </mapper>
```